# How to declare a global variable in html file which can be used by another html file as well of same project

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

I have 2 html files

file 1 : That has pop up form using data fancy box

file 2 : where pop-up form has called at different place on same page

I want to declare a global variable in file 2 which will be called in file 1 to put conditions further.
Can anyone tell me how is it possible?

Comment: Use localStorage

Answer (score 0):

Create a common Js File and declare the variable in that file.

> Import that js file in two index files and you can use that variable.